# Is there a static function in Apache common math to evaluate the Gaussian function

Tags: java, math, static-libraries, apache-commons, gaussian

In Apache commons Math there is a class Mean. I want to avoid instantiating a object every time I wanted to calculate a mean. Upon further examination I found a class StatUtils which has a static function that calculates a mean of a double[]. 
Now I want to evaluate the Gaussian function. I found a class Gaussian. But I still would rather not instantiate a object every time I want to evaluate the function. Is there a class similar to the StatUtils with static functions for evaluating the Gaussian function.

I considered instantiating a global object of type Mean to get access to the mean function without having to instantiate multiple Mean objects but when I found StatUtil I preferred that approach. For the Gaussian problem even a Global object is not acceptable since the constructor requires a mean and a sigma parameter. Therefore I would still have to instantiate a new object for each distribution.

What I am looking for is something like:

double y = gaussian(x, mean, sigma);

to summarize.

1. Is there a static function to evaluate the Gaussian function.
2. Is there a software design issue that is driving the Apache Math library design that I am missing. Is there something wrong with the StatUtils or Java.Math approach using static functions.

Comment: Why don't you want to instantiate an object? Java is an Object-Oriented language. Instantiating objects is what you do in Java!

Comment: `java.math` only contains very simple functions that don't require state. The `Gaussian` class contains state and implements several operations on the state in an OO manner.

Comment: reply to Erwin Bolwidt's comment. your comment about the state of the Gaussian object is a good point. That explains why some functions make sense as static functions. As for why I would like to avoid creating objects in the case of the Mean it seemed unnecessary,

Comment: Sorry my last comment was not completed. I did not intend to critizes the apache design. I was not clear on the advantages of the of the design over a static function design with the state (mean and sigma) passed as arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you don't need the infrastructure with derivatives and parametrics that is associated with the original class, it should be possible to extract the relevant computation (which does not contain any real "state", but only depends on the three parameters that you mentioned) and place it into a single static method.

Based on the original Gaussian class, it should roughly look like this:

```
// Based on the Gaussian class from Apache Commons Math
public static double gaussian(double x, double mean, double sigma)
{
    double norm = 1 / (sigma * Math.sqrt(2 * Math.PI));
    double  is = 1 / sigma;
    double i2s2 = 0.5 * is * is;
    double xMinusMean = x - mean;
    return norm * Math.exp(-xMinusMean * xMinusMean * i2s2);
}
```

Comment: reply to  Marco13 Yes in fact I am trying to replace my own math library with the apache library. My math library is a collection of functions written over the years. I have a function such as you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the probability density function PDF or the cumulative density function CDF. The PDF is given by @Marco13 answer.  For most statistical applications its the CDF which is most interesting finding the probability that x

What you can do is have one instance of org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.NormalDistribution which mean 0 and standard deviation 1. You can rescale the values to match

```
static NormalDistribution dist = new NormalDistribution();

static double density(double x, double mean, double sd) {
    double scaledx = (x-mean)/sd;
    return dist.density(scaledx);
}

static double cumulativeProbability(double x, double mean, double sd) {
    double scaledx = (x-mean)/sd;
    return dist.cumulativeProbability(scaledx);
}
```